# How to say "I ate too much" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german

How to say "I ate too much." in German? Is "I ate too much" not proper English?

Comment: How does the second question belong in GLU?

Comment: For a more informal / common translation: > Ich hab' zu viel gegessen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Ich habe zu viel gegessen.
```

Adding more details to your sentence in english could make it sound a bit more "proper".

Comment: Ich habe zu viel gegessen, this means "I ate so much"?

Comment: I guess "I ate so much" would directly translate to "Ich habe so viel gegessen". There is a difference between "so much" and "too much" because the latter one has more or less a negative meaning to it.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously *"I ate too much"* is mostly used in a colloquial setting. Therefore in addition to  the correct literal translation *"Ich habe zu viel gegessen"* we do have several colloquial variants we may probably hear more often:

> *Ich kann nicht mehr.
>
>   Ich bin pappsatt.
>
>   Ich platze.*

Comment: Mutter gab mir und meinen 3 Schwestern 12 Waffeln. Ich aß meine 4 schon auf, aber sie behauptet ich aß zu viel, dabei bin ich gar nicht satt.

Comment: Additionally, the colloquial: "Ich bin voll." and the very very colloquial: "Ich hab(e) mich überfressen."